# Batch file to copy list of files including subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, directory, copy-paste

I often have to track down files at work, pulling a hundred or so out of a list of a thousand, so I created a batch file that would copy the files in a location that are listed in a csv in the batch files directory and then paste them in a folder on my desktop.

This worked, but I often have to do this for hundreds of files across a dozen or so directories, so I tried to modify it to include subdirectories.  I'm having an issue getting it to work and I was wondering if the excellent people at StackOverflow could help.  Thanks!

```
@echo on
set theDest="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Batch Copies %date:/=%"
set /p MY_TEXT=<FileList.csv
echo.%MY_TEXT%
set MY_TEXT=%MY_TEXT:"",""=,%
echo.%MY_TEXT%
if not exist %theDest% md %theDest%
pause
for /R %MY_TEXT% %%G IN (.) do (
for /F  "skip=1 delims=" %%f in (FileList.csv) do (
    if exist  "%MY_TEXT%\%%f.*" (
        copy "%MY_TEXT%\%%f.*" %theDest%
         ) else (
    if exist  "%MY_TEXT%\%%f" (
         copy /R "%MY_TEXT%\%%f" %theDest%
         ) else echo "%MY_TEXT%\%%f" does not exist && echo         0 file^(s^) copied.  && echo      ERROR: %%f not found && echo.  && pause)



)   
)
echo. && echo. && echo Process Completed. &&echo.
pause
```

Part of the problem is I was just getting into batch when I wrote this and then left it and am trying to come back and figure out how everything works so I've probably messed it up more ways than one.

Answer (score 0):

So the FOR loop has a /R option which will run the same command across all subdirectories.

In your case, I think you want:

```
for /R %%a in (.) do call :MyCopyFunction %%a
exit /B

:MyCopyFunction [%1 is the current directory]
    echo My Current directory is %1
    [Do All your code here, using %1 as the current directory]
exit /B
```

I don't understand what your script is doing in detail, so you still have to fill in the details.

But this shows you how to traverse the entire directory structure.

Comment: So for /R %MY_TEXT% %%G IN (.) do call MyCopyFunction   :MyCopyFunction
for /F  "skip=1 delims=" %%f in (FileList.csv) do 
 if exist  "%%f.*" (
     copy "%%f.*" %theDest%
   ) else (
 if exist  "%%f" (
   copy  "%%f" %theDest%
   )

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to get it to work.  is it how I am referencing the variable f without declaring it in the current directory?

Comment: You wrote: `for /R %MY_TEXT% %%G`.  I have no idea why `%MY_TEXT%` is in the middle of the loop??

Comment: sorry, %MY_TEXT% is the initial directory.  Since it's looping through subdirectories should I use %%G to check if the file exists? or would %%f be sufficient?

Comment: `for /R "%MY_TEST%" %%G in (.) do `?